# How to invoke a method with pointer receiver after type assertion?

Tags: pointers, go, interface, type-conversion

I am learning interface, type conversions and methods with pointer receivers.
The rules and terminology behind pointer receiver methods are confusing to me.
Let me demonstrate my confusion with one program.

This is my Go program.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Employee struct {
    Name string
}

func (e Employee) Hi() {
    fmt.Printf("Hi! I am %s.\n", e.Name)
}

func (e *Employee) Hello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello! I am %s.\n", e.Name)
}

func main() {
    var a Employee = Employee{"Alice"}
    a.Hi()
    a.Hello()

    var b interface{} = Employee{"Bob"}
    b.(Employee).Hi()
    // b.(Employee).Hello()
}
```

This is the output.

```
Hi! I am Alice.
Hello! I am Alice.
Hi! I am Bob.
```

If I remove the last commented out line, I get this error.

```
# command-line-arguments
./foo.go:24: cannot call pointer method on b.(Employee)
./foo.go:24: cannot take the address of b.(Employee)
```

How can I fix that line of code so that I am able to invoke the method with
pointer receiver? Please explain a solution with some clarification on why this
does not work by laying down the concepts of methods with pointer receiver.

Comment: peterSo's answer is very good. Just one remark: To invoke a pointer receiver method you need a pointer to the value. This pointer can be explicit or implicit but you formally must have a pointer which requires an _adressable_ variable and not everything in Go is addressable: prominent examples are values in interfaces (your case here) and map entries. In these cases you have to "copy the unaddressable value out of the interface/the map" to get an addressable value from which you can get a pointer and invoke a pointer receiver method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't (in this case implicitly for a pointer receiver) take the address of the result of an expression (`b.(Employee)`). You can take the address of a variable. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Employee struct {
    Name string
}

func (e Employee) Hi() {
    fmt.Printf("Hi! I am %s.\n", e.Name)
}

func (e *Employee) Hello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello! I am %s.\n", e.Name)
}

func main() {
    var a Employee = Employee{"Alice"}
    a.Hi()
    a.Hello()

    var b interface{} = Employee{"Bob"}
    b.(Employee).Hi()
    // b.(Employee).Hello()
    // main.go:24: cannot call pointer method on b.(Employee)
    // main.go:24: cannot take the address of b.(Employee)
    e := b.(Employee)  // e, a variable, is addressable
    e.Hello()

    var c interface{} = &Employee{"Chris"}
    c.(*Employee).Hi()
    c.(*Employee).Hello()
}
```

Output:

```
Hi! I am Alice.
Hello! I am Alice.
Hi! I am Bob.
Hello! I am Bob.
Hi! I am Chris.
Hello! I am Chris.
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)
>
> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
>
> If the type assertion holds, the value of the expression is the value
>   stored in x and its type is T. If the type assertion is false, a
>   run-time panic occurs.
>
> [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)
>
> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x
>   contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list
>   of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is
>   shorthand for (&x).m()
>
> [Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)
>
> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a
>   pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is,
>   either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation;
>   or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array
>   indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the
>   addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized)
>   composite literal.

The value of the type assertion `b.(Employee)` is of type `Employee`. The method call `b.(Employee).Hello()` is shorthand for `(&b.(Employee)).Hello()` since `func (e *Employee) Hello()` has a pointer receiver. But, `b.(Employee)`, an expression, is not addressable. Therefore,

```
error: cannot call pointer method on b.(Employee)
error: cannot take the address of b.(Employee)
```

Answer (score -1):

The fix would be:

```
var b interface{} = &Employee{"Bob"}
b.(*Employee).Hello()
```

Here b is an interface that is actually a "pointer to Employee" and then same has been type asserted. The thing to remember is that "Employee" and "pointer to Employee" are two different types altogether.

Comment: Downvoter(s) cares to comment? If no, then you have my sympathy with you.